# If I change my owner and active keys. Does my funds also move over too?

Tags: meet.one-wallet, active-key, owner-key

I'm using the meet.one app and there is the option to change the active and owner keys under "authority management". Will this affect my balance if I change both of these keys to something else?

Comment: no, it won't affect your balance

Comment: the purpose of changing the public keys is to remove access of an hacker that has stolen access to your account right?

Comment: that can be one of them. you may want to change your keys to give more people access under a multisig design, you may want to transfer your account to someone else, you may think you have too many accounts managed by the same key(s), etc

Comment: I see. so a private key can actually own many different account names.

Comment: yes that's correct